# Основы js: как правильно использовать if else в функциях

Tags: javascript

Почему выполняется оба варианта при любом значении?

```
function message(ask = prompt("Сколько вам лет?")){
if(ask < 18){
    alert("You are not allowed")
    
}
else(ask => 18);{
    alert("You are welcome")
    }
}

message();
```

Comment: А вы точно знаете синтаксис `if/else` ? а то что-то по примеру этого не видно .........да и тем более с лишней `;` посередине кода

Comment: Вот это вообще стрелочная функция `ask => 18` и она всегда `true`

Comment: Выражение больше или равно выглядит так `>=`.
А ask => 18 - это функция. Вы можете убедиться в этом, если вызовете `typeof (ask => 18)`

Comment: Ну и в ask у вас строка, а результат сравнения чисел и строк порой бывает неожиданным. В общем действительно стоит начать с основ. Например с учебника learn.javascript.ru

Comment: ``alert("You are welcome")`` вообще за пределами if-else. Нужно быть внимательнее с ``;``

Comment: Эникейщик, у меня редактор подчеркивает красным фигурную скобку если перед ней нет точки с запятой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В JavaScript [оператор else](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) не принимает условие в скобках

```
function message(ask = prompt("Сколько вам лет?")) {
    if (ask < 18) {
       alert("You are not allowed");
    } else if (ask >= 18) {
        alert("You are welcome");
    }
}

message();
```

Можно сжать это условие в одну строку, используя [тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

```
function message(ask = prompt("Сколько вам лет?")) {
   alert(ask < 18 ? "You are not allowed" : "You are welcome");
}

message();
```

Функция message с использованием [стрелочной функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
const message = (ask = prompt("Сколько вам лет?")) => alert(ask < 18 ? "You are not allowed" : "You are welcome");

message();
```

---

[(>=) Возвращает true, если операнд слева больше или равен операнду справа.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_operators#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 0):

создает анонимную функцию:

```js
(ask => 18)
```

```js
if (...) { ... } else (/* тут создастся функция */);/* после точки с запятой else будет выполнено */{
    // выражение в фигурных скобках просто выполнится
    // фигурные скобки нужны для ограничения области видимости let и const
    alert("You are welcome")
    }
```

Подробнее по фигурные скобки и область видимости:

```js
{ const x = 42 }
console.log(x) // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

Это довольно таки элементарное тестовое задание, которое показывает, что ты не готов еще быть программистом... Надо еще на "кошках потренироваться"